# Is it possible to "launch" jupyter from within an active console/REPL/kernel/runtime

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, arcgis, jupyter, qgis

Assuming my python env has all necessary dependencies, is something like this possible:

```
# pseudo-code
# from within a NON-jupyter REPL/console
import jupyter
jupyter.start("/notebook/or/folder/")
```

Use-case:
Launch jupyter from within the ArcGIS or QGIS python console, such that we can interact with documents and their layers/data.

Or can anyone recommend alternate methods to accomplish the same result?

Comment: `In [853]: !jupyter notebook&` does it for me

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, but your idea uses magic to step outside a jupyter REPL, but I need something that i can launch from within a NON-jupyter python REPL (eg: The ArcGIS or QGIS python console.)

Comment: `subprocess` is the standard module for starting other processes.